# FreePBX add a new SIP extension

Tags: asterisk, freepbx

I've successfully built VoIP server with FreePBX Asterisk. It works fine when I register a user on FreePBX. However, I would like to register a SIP account from mobile device directly. I found out that I can add custom information into FreePBX MySQL database.

However, it doesn't work either, and I couldn't find a place to insert SIP password.. Someone said that I need to do something with /var/www/html/admin/functions.inc.php file. Is there better way to create a new SIP extension from outside of FreePBX GUI? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Freepbx not use database way(asterisk realtime).

Instead it use text file method.

After adding new info into mysql database, you have apply changes on web to write new config files. You can do same from command line interface (see amp_engine), but can't do that using db query.

Other option is use freepbx framework.php correctly.

Also you can use asterisk realtime architecture and not use freepbx dialplan.

**WARNING** Freepbx is designed for low number of extensions and low load(branch office pbx). As result using it for support mobile device application will be great fail. Check other projects, for example a2billing.org or hire expert to build core server with HA/failover for your need.

Comment: This is perfect answer for me. I had to restart asterisk to apply FreePBX MySQL database that I changed. I will start over to use original asterisk. Thank you!